# Dynamic Memory Allocation in kernel's VDSO

Tags: linux-kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation, vdso

For an experiment, I need to instrument and allocate entry nodes for a hashtable inside `arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.c` through the following typical approach.

```
struct h_struct *phe =  (struct h_struct*) kmalloc(sizeof(struct h_struct), GFP_HIGHUSER);
```

that I have tested and used in other areas of kernel where it compiled and worked as expected. However, in the case of VDSO it results in the failed linking

```
  CC      arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.o
  VDSO    arch/x86/vdso/vdso.so.dbg
arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.o: In function `kmalloc':
linux-3.10.0/include/linux/slub_def.h:171: undefined reference to `kmalloc_caches'
linux-3.10.0/include/linux/slub_def.h:171: undefined reference to `kmem_cache_alloc_trace'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/vdso/vdso.so
```

I am aware that VDSO has a special status, where although allocated in kernel space is mapped into userspace in the address space of every process.

I wonder, if someone more experienced can spot or suggest the way to allocate memory in vdso for my needs.

P.S. `malloc` can't be used as that requires `stdlib.h` which results in linking against `glibc`